# Passing dynamic type, iterating fields and replacing values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have 3/4 different models that each contain their own nested model.  I need a way of iterating all fields, including those of the nested model and do a string replace (although not all fields are strings).

My initial idea was to write a method which allows for a 'dynamic' type to be passed.

Input model:

```
Name = Joe
Surname = Smith
Address = new ClientAddress
   {
    Line1: Item A
    Line2: mistake
    Line3: mistake
   }
```

My example method:

```
MyMethod (dynamic passInModel)
{
  ....
  passInModel.Replace("mistake","correction");

  return passInModel;
}
```

Output:

```
Name = Joe
Surname = Smith
Address = new ClientAddress
  {
   Line1: Item A
   Line2: correction
   Line3: correction
  }
```

Despite trying various ways of doing it I've not had any success in writing something that does the job.

Comment: What about passing it as an object and do some reflexing on it? I can make an example, but you should update your post with the type definition,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method that accepts an `object` and use reflection to iterate through all the fields, but you're getting into messy territory there. In my opinion, even using `dynamic` here is messy.

Consider using a modified [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) here. If your domain objects look like this:

```
public class ModelBase
{
}

public class MyModel1 : ModelBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public ClientAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class MyModel2 : ModelBase
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public CompanyAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAddress
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyAddress
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> AdditionalLines { get; set; }
}
```

Write a visitor that takes an abstract `ModelBase` and dispatches the correct type-safe visitor:

```
public class ModelFixVisitor
{
    public ModelBase Visit(ModelBase model)
    {
        var asModel1 = model as MyModel1;
        if (asModel1 != null)
        {
            return new Model1FixVisitor().Visit(asModel1);
        }

        var asModel2 = model as MyModel2;
        if (asModel2 != null)
        {
            return new Model2FixVisitor().Visit(asModel2);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown model type.");
    }
}
```

Then write a simple class for each type (and subtype) you need to visit:

```
public class Model1FixVisitor
{
    public MyModel1 Visit(MyModel1 model)
    {
        model.Name = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(model.Name);
        model.Surname = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(model.Surname);
        model.Address = new ClientAddressFixVisitor().Visit(model.Address);

        return model;
    }
}

public class Model2FixVisitor
{
    public MyModel2 Visit(MyModel2 model)
    {
        model.CompanyName = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(model.CompanyName);
        model.Region = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(model.Region);
        model.Address = new CompanyAddressFixVisitor().Visit(model.Address);
        return model;
    }
}

public class ClientAddressFixVisitor
{
    public ClientAddress Visit(ClientAddress address)
    {
        address.Line1 = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(address.Line1);
        address.Line2 = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(address.Line2);
        address.Line3 = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(address.Line3);
        return address;
    }
}

public class CompanyAddressFixVisitor
{
    public CompanyAddress Visit(CompanyAddress address)
    {
        address.Line1 = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(address.Line1);
        address.Line2 = new StringFixVisitor().Visit(address.Line2);
        address.AdditionalLines = new StringListFixVisitor().Visit(address.AdditionalLines);
        return address;
    }
}

public class StringFixVisitor
{
    public string Visit(string element)
    {
        return element.Replace("mistake", "correction");
    }
}

public class StringListFixVisitor
{
    public List<string> Visit(List<string> elements)
    {
        return elements
            .Select(x => new StringFixVisitor().Visit(x))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

I'm sure the code could be refactored and optimized, but it should express the general idea.

What I like about this type of solution is that it breaks the problem down into small, manageable chunks: How do I fix a `string`? How do I fix a `ClientAddress`?

Fixing entire models then becomes simple composition of these smaller classes. It's a little more verbose, but you get to keep type safety, and don't have to mess with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the power of .Net reflection to solve this.

I created a class called DeepStringReplacer. Using reflection it iterates through object properties and if the type is string, perform string replace.

Check the code below:

```
    public class DeepStringReplacer
{        
    public object Replace(object input, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        if (input is string)
        {
            return input.ToString().Replace(oldValue, newValue);
        }
        var fields = input.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            var fieldValue = field.GetValue(input);
            field.SetValue(input, Replace(fieldValue, oldValue, newValue));
        }
        return input;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public ClientAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAddress
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }    
}
```